# Why Alfresco ignore some webscripts or templates modifications?

Tags: maven, alfresco-share

I'm using Alfresco community 4.2

I've created an AMP share module in Maven for customization and I edited several templates files, essentially commenting out/deleting some unwanted functionnalities to clean the user interface.

For some of the templates files, my modification are taken in account, for others they aren't.

Example of working modification in web-extension/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/footer/footer.get.html.ftl

I deleted the footer image with copyright and it effectively doesn't appear anymore on my Alfresco installation.

```
<@markup id="html">
   <@uniqueIdDiv>
      <#assign fc=config.scoped["Edition"]["footer"]>
      <div class="footer ${fc.getChildValue("css-class")!"footer-com"}">
      </div>
   </@>
</@>
```

Example of non-working modification in web-extension/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/navigation/collaboration-navigation.get.html.ftl

I have deleted the "Site dashboard" link and "Site member" link, but they still appear on any existing or new site I'm creating ...

```
<@markup id="html">
   <@uniqueIdDiv>
      <#assign activeSite = page.url.templateArgs.site!"">
      <#assign pageFamily = template.properties.pageFamily!"dashboard">
      <div class="site-navigation">
      <#if siteExists>
         <#if siteValid>
            <span class="navigation-separator">&nbsp;</span>
            <#list pages as p>
               <#assign linkPage=p.pageUrl!p.title/>
               <#if linkPage?index_of(pageFamily) != -1>
                  <#assign linkClass>class="active-page theme-color-4"</#assign>      
               <#else>
                  <#assign linkClass>class="theme-color-4"</#assign>
               </#if>
            <span class="navigation-item"><a href="${url.context}/page/site/${activeSite}/${linkPage}" ${linkClass}>${(p.sitePageTitle!p.title)?html}</a></span>
               <#if p_has_next>
            <span class="navigation-gap">&nbsp;</span>
               </#if>
            </#list>
         </#if>
         <span class="navigation-separator">&nbsp;</span>
      </#if>
      </div>
   </@>
</@>
```

Does someone here have an idea of what is going on ? I have the same problem when editing webscripts, but in them, my modifications are never taken in account ...

I have checked into the exploded WAR on the server, all my files are effectively present into WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/web-extension/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/* folders.

Thanks,
Jérémy

Original thread on Alfresco forums: http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/alfresco-ignore-some-webscripts-or-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved on Alfresco forum.

Short answer: Use share extension module.

Long answer: Go to the original thread http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/alfresco-ignore-some-webscripts-or-templates